# Django: best way to accessing a ForeignKey value from template

Tags: django, templates, django-models, django-templates, django-views

A Card model has many Workouts models (ForeignKey to Card), each Workout model has many Exercise names models (ForeignKey to Workout). I would like to access Exercise Name value in the template. Which is the best way?

Answer (score 1):

First please edit your question to use the proper "ForeignKey *to* X", its hard to tell what your FKs go.

But to answer your question, `foo_id` is the integer represenation of the `foo` FK field.

that is, `print record.exercise` will call `__unicode__()` on the exercice model to get the represenation to print, `print record.exercise_id` will print the actual FK id.